# How to convert an array of bytes to JSON string in Ruby

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, swift2

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Convert a Dictionary to NSData which contains normal text as well as an image:

   ```
   let payload: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "some_item": "some_value",
        "img": UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)!
   ]

   let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(payload)
   ```
2. Send this data to the server using WebSocket `writeData`
3. Parse the array of bytes to get a JSON string and save the image and send back some response.

I am using Rails4 as the backend and I have tried `pack` but it doesn't work. I am not sure if this is doable or not.

I know Base64 encoding will work instead of byte data, but it's a bit slower than what I would prefer.

Comment: why are you using `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: I wanted to convert the `Dictionary` to `NSData` so I can send it over the `webSocket`.

Comment: But NSKeyedArchiver has its own format for objects, and it needs NSKeyedUnarchiver to decode the archived contents: Ruby won't be able to do that. You should use B64 + JSON to transport your objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to stop using `NSKeyedArchiver` and instead use `NSJSONSerialization`.Tl his will generate actual JSON data for you that you should be able to unpack easily on the server.

When using an image you either:

1. don't use JSON with it
2. convert the image data into base64 and create the JSON including that text
3. use multi-part form upload with a section for the image and another for the rest of the JSON

Comment: What you suggested works fine with just text data. But `NSJSONSerialization` fails with Images.

Comment: added some options for the image part